# Regex capture group reference > repetition?

Tags: regex, capture-group

I am currently working on Regex Challenges on Hackerrank and can't find resources on to why using capture group references are preferred over repetitions. 
Here is the link to the Challenge: 
https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/chingu-challenge-8-regex/challenges/matching-same-text-again-again/problem

Why is the first option of the following two preferred over the second? (Meaning what is the difference?! The second one gives me a mistake on the challenge)

```
1.Ref. Capture Group: ^([a-z]\w\s\W\d\D[A-Z][A-Za-z][aeiouAEIOU]\S)\1$
2.Repetition:         ^([a-z]\w\s\W\d\D[A-Z][A-Za-z][aeiouAEIOU]\S){2}$
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They are just different patterns, not variations matching the same strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one matches *something that matches the group pattern* followed by *the same thing again*.

The first one matches *something that matches the group pattern* followed by *something that matches the group pattern* - it doesn't have to be the same thing again. After all, you don't expect `[a-z]{2}` to only match `aa`, `bb` etc., do you?